# How to get the largest value of a column in table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

> fileId, studentId,

Given a particular studentId, how can I get the largest fileId that is in the table ?
I saw this other query :

```
SELECT row 
FROM table 
WHERE id=(
    SELECT max(id) FROM table
    )
```

This would give the row where id is the largest. But what about the largest id for a given student id ? Is it better to match the student in the inner query or outer query ?

Comment: `select * from table where studentId = your_known_id order by fileId desc limit 1`

Comment: @Igor no i think I haven't made myself clear... say there are three rows with studentId =3, but with fileId's = {4,5,6}, how do i get the row {fileId,studentId} = {6,3}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need the whole row:

```
select * from table where studentId = your_known_id order by fileId desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems simplest:

```
SELECT studentId, MAX(ID)
FROM TableA
GROUP BY studentId
```

OR With filtering options:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
 SELECT studentId, MAX(ID)
 FROM TableA
 GROUP BY studentId
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE studentId ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> ... what about the largest id for a given student id

```
SELECT MAX(fileId)
FROM table
WHERE studentId = 123
```

Where 123 is the student if you want to filter on.

---

> say there are three rows with studentId =3, but with fileId's = {4,5,6}, how do i get the row {fileId,studentId} = {6,3}

```
SELECT MAX(fileId), studentId
FROM table
WHERE studentId = 3 
GROUP BY studentId
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT
 id,
 ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY studentId ORDER BY id desc) rnk
FROM table) a
WHERE a.rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code works as well

```
SELECT max(field) from  table_name where studenId = <someID>
```